# What is the difference between the various compiler debug flags?

Tags: debugging, linker, fortran, compiler-optimization, intel-fortran

I have found the list of ifort debug flags. However, I am confused about some explanation of debug flags. As it stated, -debug can be configured as all, full, minimal and none. May I ask what's difference between "-debug all" and "debug full" ? Which one contain more debug information?

When I use idb GUI to debug a fortran executable file, I can only set my breakpoints at some line not all of them. I wonder if it is due to level of the debug information so only some lines in source codes have been associated to the line number table in the object files. If so, how can I associate with every line in source files to my objects files?

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we disregard possible differences in versions, ***/debug:full*** and ***/debug:all*** seem to be equivalent. They generate complete debugging information ... it is also the same as just specifying ***/debug*** with no keyword. ***/debug:full*** is the default setting in the debug configuration in the Windows IDE).

Comment: @Cassie - Glad to. Sorry I couldn't help with the other part.

Comment: Hi thanks. It is ok for the other part. Because I just learned that only executable command have that kind of information.